# Les quatre pattes du tuteur se « clippent » sur le pot ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, anglicismes, emprunts

> Les quatre pattes du tuteur se *[clip](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/clip)pent* sur le pot.

[image]

Je dis ça spontanément. Je cherche une formulation *courante* avec un verbe qui *exprime bien ce que la patte fait* sur le rebord. Incidemment on peut reformuler *patte/tuteur* si le coeur nous en dit ; je veux pouvoir disserter de l'interaction entre ces divers (partie d') objets.

Answer (score 5):

> Les quatre pattes du tuteur se [clipsent](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/clipser) sur le pot.

Ce néologisme que l'on trouve dès le début des années 1960 s'est construit à partir du pluriel « clips » utilisé au singulier en français et où le *S* final était souvent prononcé (un [clips](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/clips) /klips/, comme l'a été aussi *un pin's* /pins/). Sa morphologie a peut-être aussi été influencée par « éclipser ».

> *Au même instant, le boîtier clipsé sur la poche de sa blouse sonna. L’infirmier lut le message.*
> Thierry Serfaty, *La nuit interdite*, 2006.

Il est aujourd'hui largement utilisé et compris en France. Son concurrent « clipper » me semble moins courant, sauf dans le vocabulaire de la chirurgie.

Answer (score 1):

Ce que l'on a de mieux en français serait le verbe « *accrocher* ». Le terme racine ne correspond pas exactement à « clip » (pince), mais il n'existe pas de verbe « appincer ». « Accrocher » est  moins spécifique, mais il est assez général en cela que le moyen d'un crochet n'est pas nécessaire dans l'accrochage pour qu'il puisse être employé.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accrocher)) **I.** − Emploi trans.
> **A.** − [Le suj. désigne une pers.]
> **1.** [L'obj. désigne une chose matérielle]
> **a)** Au propre. Suspendre une chose à un crochet, ou **l'attacher à l'aide d'un crochet** :

- Les quatre pattes du tuteur *s'accrochent* sur le pot. (*On utilise la forme pronominale de sens passif (le sujet subit l'action)*)

Le verbe « fixer », moins spécifique, convient aussi.

- Les quatre pattes du tuteur *se fixent* sur le pot.

Comment: qui se fixe ou s'attache **au bord du pot** supportant le tuteur.  supportant pour éviter du tuteur, qui ferait trop de du. Technique, eh?

Comment: @Lambie  Un salmigondis pas clair du tout…

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa « À » et « sur » conviennent tous les deux ; même lorsque l'on dit « sur », qui est plus spécifique, on aura besoin parfois pour être vraiment précis d'ajouter « dessus » (Ex. : Ça s'attache sur le pot, dessus.).  Par exemple on _monte un moteur **sur** une voiture_ mais jamais  « dans » n'est utilisé pour cette opération ; dans ce cas  seulement « sur » est idiomatique ; pour ce qui est de s'installer au volant, c'est « monter **dans** sa voiture », et « sur » ne convient pas du tout.

Comment: "j'ai mis un tuteur en métal qui va jusqu'au fond du pot qui est lesté de cailloux mais ça tient pas sur le long terme...faudrait que **je le fixe carrément au bord du pot** je pense"...https://www.forums-orchidees.fr/topic/93778-question-laelia/page/2/